# keycloak command line login with client_assertion example

Tags: curl, jwt, keycloak, keycloak-services

"I've been searching for a way to authenticate with keyloak using curl but haven't had too much luck. Here's my curl sample:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
 -d "username=user" \
 -d "password=user" \
 -d "grant_type=password" \
 -d "client_id=master" \
 -d "requested_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:refresh_token" \
 -d "client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer" \
 -d "client_assertion={signed_jwt}" \
 -d "audience=master"
```

I'm not able to figure out how to set/create the **signed_jwt** parameter. I only have a **jks** file and the **keycloak.json** config. Any help much appreciated."

Comment: What is your exact requirement ,you are not able to get access token through curl ?

Comment: "I need a way to create a signed jwt for the client_assertion parameter. I'm only using signed jwt without a client secret using jwks uri to authenticate with my sample app. I've tried using node-jose-tools but still wasn't able get anything working."

Comment: @mcapptivate, did you manage to find the signed_jwt?

Comment: "Not with curl. I ended up forking an Auth0 node library and modifying their code to get it to work. [link](https://github.com/tdespenza/node-jwks-rsa)"